# Unable to use Jquery UI effects inside a HTML Dialog using GAS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-apps-script

I need scrolling effect in HTML Dialog of Google Apps Script.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IHf2SkmoEyxDAs86FIdHWKfQ19i19-jUDFDlbMKJE8A/copy is what I have tried, The code is also placed in the code editor.

When Highlight buttons are pressed its highlighting but not scrolling when the html code is placed in HTML dialog.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>   
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
   <style>
      .sidebar{padding:0}
      .branding-below {
      bottom: 80px;
      top: 0;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <div class="sidebar branding-below" data-select2-id="58">
         <div class="block">
            <div id="main">
               <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel3')" >Highlight sel3</button>
               <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel5')">Highlight sel5</button>
               <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel7')">Highlight sel7</button>
               <br/>
               <br/>
               <table border="0" id="fields" style="padding:5px;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
                  <tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="gray" colspan="2">
                        <select class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel1">
                           <option>Example0 test</option>
                           <option>Beta test</option>
                        </select>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="gray" colspan="2">
                        <select  class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel2">
                           <option>Example1 test</option>
                           <option>Beta test</option>
                        </select>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="gray" colspan="2">
                        <select class="field"  style="width:50%" id="sel3">
                           <option>Example3 test</option>
                           <option>Beta test</option>
                        </select>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="gray" colspan="2">
                        <select  class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel4">
                           <option>Alpha test</option>
                           <option>Beta test</option>
                        </select>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="gray" colspan="2">
                        <select  class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel5">
                           <option>Alpha test</option>
                           <option>Beta test</option>
                        </select>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="gray" colspan="2">
                        <select  class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel6">
                           <option>Alpha test</option>
                           <option>Beta test</option>
                        </select>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td class="gray" colspan="2">
                        <select  class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel7">
                           <option>Alpha test</option>
                           <option>Beta test</option>
                        </select>
                  </tr>
               </table>
               <br/>
               <br/>
               <br/>
               <br/>
               <br/>
               <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel3')" >Highlight sel3</button>
               <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel5')">Highlight sel5</button>
               <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel7')">Highlight sel7</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar bottom">
         <table width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed;">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:0px;" align="left">
                     <small align="center" id="status"></small>&emsp;
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" align="right">
                     <button id="reset">Reset</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
      <script>
         function highlightSelect2(selector) {
            $(selector)
                .next(".select2-container")
                .find(".select2-selection")
                .effect("highlight", {
                    color: "#f88"
                }, 10000);
            
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top
            }, 1000);
         }
         $(document).ready(function () {
          $('select').select2();
           listen("select")
          
         });
         
         function listen(selector)
         {
         $(selector).on('change', function() {
         alert("Cannot use this field as you have already used!");
         highlightSelect2("#sel7")
         $(this).val("");
         });
         }         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the animate on the `.sidebar`

```js
function highlightSelect2(selector) {
  $(selector)
    .next(".select2-container")
    .find(".select2-selection")
    .effect("highlight", {
      color: "#f88"
    }, 10000);
  $('.sidebar').animate({
    scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').select2();
  listen("select")

});

function listen(selector) {
  $(selector).on('change', function() {
    alert("Cannot use this field as you have already used!");
    highlightSelect2("#sel7")
    $(this).val("");
  });
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  padding: 0
}

.branding-below {
  bottom: 80px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<div class="sidebar branding-below" data-select2-id="58">
  <div class="block">
    <div id="main">
      <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel3')">Highlight sel3</button>
      <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel5')">Highlight sel5</button>
      <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel7')">Highlight sel7</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <table border="0" id="fields" style="padding:5px;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;">
        <tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="gray" colspan="2">
              <select class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel1">
                <option>Example0 test</option>
                <option>Beta test</option>
              </select>
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="gray" colspan="2">
              <select class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel2">
                <option>Example1 test</option>
                <option>Beta test</option>
              </select>
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="gray" colspan="2">
              <select class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel3">
                <option>Example3 test</option>
                <option>Beta test</option>
              </select>
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="gray" colspan="2">
              <select class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel4">
                <option>Alpha test</option>
                <option>Beta test</option>
              </select>
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="gray" colspan="2">
              <select class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel5">
                <option>Alpha test</option>
                <option>Beta test</option>
              </select>
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="gray" colspan="2">
              <select class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel6">
                <option>Alpha test</option>
                <option>Beta test</option>
              </select>
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
              <br />
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="gray" colspan="2">
              <select class="field" style="width:50%" id="sel7">
                <option>Alpha test</option>
                <option>Beta test</option>
              </select>
          </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel3')">Highlight sel3</button>
      <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel5')">Highlight sel5</button>
      <button onclick="highlightSelect2('#sel7')">Highlight sel7</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar bottom">
  <table width="100%" style="table-layout:fixed;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:0px;" align="left">
          <small align="center" id="status"></small>&emsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
          <button id="reset">Reset</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```